# Ruby on Rails Installation Error port 53

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

Need some help trying to install bundler for ruby on rails. When I enter gem install bundler this is the error that occurs. Thanks in advance!

```
C:\Sites>gem install bundler ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - sendto(2) for "255.255.255.255" port 53
```

Comment: Port 53 is DNS. Do normal DNS lookups work for you? Are you running some kind of (personal) firewall that might be blocking DNS lookups from unknown applications?

Comment: I tried uninstalling my anti-virus. didn't work tho :/

Comment: Have you checked whether DNS lookups work? Have you tried more verbose settings, e.g. `gem install -V --debug bundler` ?

Answer (score 0):

@frank-schmitt has the correct answer here.  I was running into this exact problem.  the --debug made it clear that nothing was listening on DNS port 53.  Confirmed with:

`netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "`

Installing **bind** (DNS Server) on Ubuntu 16.04 resolved this issue.

Comment: I'm on windows 10, so is their an equivalent to solution for that?

Comment: The underlying problem is likely the same - your PC is not answering DNS requests.  Things to try: A) Double check all of your network settins - especially gateway.  B) Ensure that your local firewall/antivirus is NOT blocking port 53.  From Googling it appears netstat does work on windows.  C) search on "Windows 10 not responding to DNS requests" and try some of those solutions.  Hope that helps